Growth order of $e^{p(z)}$ for a complex polynomial, $p(z)$
Let $p(z):\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a degree $m$ polynomial, and consider $e^{p(z)}$. I'm wondering whether it's true that the order of $e^{p(z)}$ is equal to the degree of $p(z)$. My working definition is that $f$ has order less than $\rho$ if
$$|f(z)|\le Ae^{B|z|^\rho}, $$
for some $A,B \in \mathbb{R}$, and all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, and the order of $f$ is inf$\{\rho:$ $f$ has order $\le \rho\}$.
One can expand $e^{p(z)}$ as $e^{a_0}\cdot e^{a_1z}\cdot \cdots \cdot e^{a_mz^m},$ and then pretty easily show
$$|e^{p(z)}|\le e^{B|z|^m} $$
for some $B \in \mathbb{R}$, so $e^{p(z)}$ has order less than or equal to $m$. We want to show that if
$$|e^{p(z)}|\le Ce^{D|z|^\rho} $$
for some $C,D \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\rho\ge m$.
Assume the contrary, that
$$|e^{p(z)}|\le Ce^{D|z|^\rho} $$
for some $\rho<m$. Then, for all $x>0$,
$$e^{p(x)}\le Ce^{Dx^\rho} $$
which implies (by taking the logrithm),
$$p(x)\le \log(C)+Dx^\rho \implies p(x)-Dx^\rho\le \log(C).$$
My goal in this is to generate a contradiction, and therefore prove that the order of $e^{p(z)}=m$, but the above did not generate the desired contradiction, as depending on $C$ and the polynomial $p(z)$, there's no problem. However, I'm pretty sure that the order of $e^{p(z)}$ should be $m$, as there's a problem I'm working on that seems to hinge on this fact.
Is there a way to prove this statement? Or am I trying to prove something that, in general, is false?

Note that $p(x)$ might not be real-valued, so we need $e^{\Re p(x)}$ instead of $e^{p(x)}$. But even without this, $p(x)$ might be negative for all $x\in\Bbb R$ which would make such inequalities true, so we can't just restrict to real inputs. Hint: if the leading term of $p(z)$ is $c_m z^m$, restrict attention to $\arg z = -\frac1m\arg c_m$.

Got it. Thank you!
